# Finding a parametric solution via three specific solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear equation $$x - y + 2z = 3$$ has $[3, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]$, and $[6, 1, -1]$ as specific solutions.

The complete set of solutions corresponds to the set of points in the plane determined by the given equation. If we set $y = s$ and $z = t$, then a parametric solution is given by $[3 + s - 2t, s, t]$.

How do they found this parametric solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously,

$$x=3+y-2z.$$

You can rewrite this as

$$\begin{cases}x=3+s-2t,\\y=s,\\z=t.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\space x-y+2z = 3 \\
&\Rightarrow x = 3 - 2t + s \\
&\Rightarrow [x,y,z]=[3-2t+s,s,t]
\end{align}

Note that I used $y = s, z = t$ in the last step.

Answer (score -1):

$$x-y+2z=3\implies x=3+y-2z$$

They then switched $y\iff s$, and  $z\iff t$

Comment: I have left a downvote since this does not answer the question, in my opinion. The point is to find the general solution using knowledge only of the specific solutions, rather than finding the general solution by directly solving the equation.

Comment: Oops, I would like to rescind my downvote, since after thinking more about this I realized I was misreading the question...

Answer (score -1):

Note that $x=3+y-2z$. Let $y=s$ and $z=t$. Then,

$x=3+s-2t$

Thus, the parametric form in terms of $s$ and $t$ is $[3 + s - 2t, s, t]$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Don't you use the specific solutions [3,0,0],[0,1,2], and [6,1,−1] to define the parametric solution? 

And what do the last two variables (*s* and *t*) in the parametric solution stand for, why do you include these two variables in the parametric form?

Comment: @ Vera - there is nothing special about those three points. You don’t need to use them. $s$ and $t$ are just variables to parametrize the plane. The point on the plane varies with varying $s$ and $t$. Unlike a line which requires only one variable to parametrize, a plane needs two parameters, in this case, $s$ and $t$

Comment: Also note that there is more than one way to parametrize a plane.

Comment: I have left a downvote since this answer (in my opinion) is not answering the question that was asked - instead, it is suggesting a different technique to solve the problem.

Comment: Oops, I would like to rescind my downvote, since after thinking more about this I realized I was misreading the question...